# jquery custom function call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I'm new to jquery, ajax and jstree. I'm using jstree to have my `<ul>` elements look like a tree structure. 
I have the `<ul>` under a `div` tag of id = "container". When I execute the html file, the div (id = "container") is passed to jstree function as follows:

```
$(function() {
   $('#container').jstree();
});
```

My html snippet is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id = "treeNodes">
        <li>Parent
            <ul>
                <li>Child1
                    <ul>
                        <li>child2-1</li>
                        <li>child2-2</li>
                        <li>child2-3</li>
                        <li>child2-4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The tree structure is being displayed fine.

I'm trying to write a jquery function that gets the **li** element's name as an argument. 
For example: when I click **Parent**, the function should recieve "Parent" as an argument or when I click **child2-3**, the function should get "child2-3" as the argument.

I attempted to create that function, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my attempt -

```
$("#treeNodes li").click(function() {  
   console.log("hello"); 
   console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

The control seems to go to the function calling the jstree(), but the other function doesn't seem to work.
Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the code is inside `$(...)`, just like the `jstree()` call.

Comment: This has to do with the fact that after the `.jstree()` call, the HTML structure is modified and items get classes added to them. Inspect the resulting HTML and you'll see that there are new `<a>` and `<i>` elements that get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your structure into a JSTree causes new HTML to be created and those new elements have custom classes and new APIs. So, you have to read the documentation to understand how to use the new structure.

If you look at **[this documentation page](https://www.jstree.com/docs/events/)**, you'll see an example of what you are after, which hinges on a custom `changed` event. I've reproduced that example, customizing it for your HTML and `console` output.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container')
  // listen for  the custom "changed" event on any jstree
  .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    // When you click on a JSTree the event appears to fire on the entire tree
    // You'll have to iterate the tree nodes for the selected one.
    var i, j, r = [];
    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
      r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text);
    }
    console.clear();
    console.log('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
  })
  // create the instance
  .jstree();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul id = "treeNodes">
        <li>Parent
            <ul>
                <li>Child1
                    <ul>
                        <li>child2-1</li>
                        <li>child2-2</li>
                        <li>child2-3</li>
                        <li>child2-4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have read the documentation from the jstree page: https://www.jstree.com/

There is a class from the jstree called jstree-children, from that class you can obtain the value from the list, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.jstree-children ul li', function (e) { 
console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Mantixd/0jwpz2r1/

Comment: This code does respond to clicks, but it doesn't produce the results that were asked for. In order to do that, a different approach is required. See my answer above for details.